# Issues changing the datatype of an array from double to int

Tags: python, pyspark, databricks

I have a set of data and I am trying to write a python program that changes the datatypes from the schema level when loading the file in databricks. while changing the datatype of the array from DOUBLE to INT i keep getting errors

The schema

```
root
 |-- _id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- city: string (nullable = true)
 |-- loc: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: double (containsNull = true)
 |-- pop: long (nullable = true)
 |-- state: string (nullable = true)
```

my codes

```
s= StructType([
StructField("_id",IntegerType(), True),
StructField("city",StringType(), True),
StructField("loc",ArrayType(), True),
StructField("element",DoubleType(), True),
StructField("pop",LongType(), True),
StructField("state",StringType(), True)
])

filepath= "/FileStore/tables/zips.json"
df2= spark.read.format("json").load(filepath, schema=s)
df2.show()
```

errors

```
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'elementType'
```

sample data

[image]

Comment: It's an import error, the package/module you are looking for is somewhere else/doesn't exist. Maybe because there is no 'elementType' class in pyspark.sql.types?[Documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql.html#data-types)

Comment: thanks for the response, is there another way to change the double to int

Comment: Umm, I don't see anything wrong with your method, so could you edit your post to include your imports, because that is where the problem was?

Comment: Please I updated the error message

Comment: One issue I can see is that you have written ArrayType() without any type. If you check the [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.types.ArrayType.html#arraytype), you see that ArrayType() needs a parameter, which would be the type of element the array will contain.

Comment: It seems to be `StructField("loc",ArrayType(IntegerType()), True)` what you would need for that. `element` in your example would be just another field on roor-level.

Comment: That makes so much sense. I am getting another set of errors though.. I added this:  StructField("loc", ArrayType(IntegerType, True)). now I get this error: 
AssertionError: elementType <class 'pyspark.sql.types.IntegerType'> should be an instance of <class 'pyspark.sql.types.DataType'>

Comment: @tevemadar I tried your approach and it worked but not sure how to represent the "element" at root-level. I did it at the previous fields but i got nulls as values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your schema definition is incorrect

```py
s= StructType([
StructField("_id",IntegerType(), True),
StructField("city",StringType(), True),
StructField("loc",ArrayType(DoubleType()), True),
StructField("element",DoubleType(), True),
StructField("pop",LongType(), True),
StructField("state",StringType(), True)
])

# "flatten" `lat` and `lon` from `loc` array
filepath= "/FileStore/tables/zips.json"
df2= (spark
    .read.format("json").load(filepath, schema=s)
    .withColumn('loc', F.array(
      F.col('loc')[0].cast('int'),
      F.col('loc')[1].cast('int')
    ))
)
df2.show()

# +---+----+------------+-----+-----+---+---+
# |_id|city|         loc|  pop|state|lat|lon|
# +---+----+------------+-----+-----+---+---+
# |  1|  CC|[77.3, 77.2]|12345|   SS| 77| 77|
# +---+----+------------+-----+-----+---+---+
```

Comment: thanks for the response. I am trying to change the datatypes especially the 'loc' element from double to int

Comment: it looks good but i am getting an error : 
NameError: name 'col' is not defined

Comment: My bad, I used `F.col` but you just need `col`

Comment: Same error boss man, but the idea is to have loc as [77, 77]

Comment: Ah, you probably not import yet, try `from pyspark.sql.functions import *`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232533/discussion-between-lee-and-pltc).

Answer (score 0):

You missed passing one parameter in **ArrayType(elementType)**

**Error: elementType should be DataType**

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *

ArrayType(IntegerType())
```

Check here for more: [Documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.types.ArrayType.html)